# I have a problem in text alignment of some data that is being sent from popup modal to its parent view textarea

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textarea, text-alignment

There is some data that is being sent from popup modal to its parent view textarea.This text is not being aligned properly, I am not well versed with javascript so i need some help.
Also i want to close the modal popup after data is being sent which is not happening currently any help would be appreciated.

I have tried a few html elements for text formatting but none of use

This is the code that sends data from popup (table) to the parent view textarea

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Assign Click event to Button.
        $("#btnGet").click(function () {
            var snddata = "";

            //Loop through all checked CheckBoxes in list.
            $("#example  input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
                snddata += "Name : " + row.cells[2].innerHTML;
                snddata += "Designation : " + row.cells[3].innerHTML;
                snddata += "Experience : " + row.cells[4].innerHTML;
                snddata += "Location : " + row.cells[5].innerHTML;
                snddata += "Salary : " + row.cells[6].innerHTML;
                snddata += "Skill : " + row.cells[7].innerHTML;
                snddata += "JD : " + row.cells[8].innerHTML;
                snddata += "Criteria : " + row.cells[9].innerHTML;
                snddata += "-------------------------\n";
            });

            //Display selected Row data in Alert Box.

            alert(snddata);

            //mailtxt is the id for parent view textarea

            $("#mailtxt").val(snddata);
            closeModal();
            return false;
           @* @message=snddata;*@

        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the output that im getting :

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDDaQ.jpg)

This is what i am expecting :
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV44k.jpg)

Comment: Both images are same..

Comment: sorry my mistake...i updated the images